# Weird result with rapidXml in C++ append_node

Tags: c++, rapidxml

I have this class:

```
// XmlWrapper.h
class XmlWrapper{
private:
    xml_document<> doc;
public:
    XmlWrapper();
    string addNode( string node_name);
            string getXmlString();
};

// XmlWrapper.cpp
XmlWrapper::XmlWrapper(){};

XmlWrapper::addNode(string node_name){
    char _name[name.size()+1];
    strcpy(_name,name.c_str());
    _name[name.size()] = '\0';
    xml_node<> *root = doc.allocate_node(node_element,_name);
    this->doc.append_node(root);
    delete root;
    return SUCCESS;
}

string XmlWrapper::getXmlString(){
    string xmlString;
    print(back_inserter(xmlString), this->doc, 0);
    return xmlString;
}
```

And this is my main.cpp:

```
XmlWrapper wrapper;
wrapper.addNode("message");
cout << wrapper.getXmlString() << endl;
```

However, my result is a list of weird thing!! if i cout `wrapper.getXmlString()` in `addNode` function, the result will be okie! So what's is my problem?

Edited:
if i use directly in main.cpp like this below,every thing is go right:

```
xml_document<> doc;
xml_node<> *message_node = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "message");
doc.append_node(message_node);
string buffer;
print(back_inserter(buffer),doc,0);
cout << buffer << endl;
```

Why this thing happen?

Comment: You're not using `new` to allocate memory. Why do you have the `delete root;` statement then? Further, for the node names to stick, you should probably use `allocate_string`. Read the documentation.

Comment: I'm just worried about memory leak! Is this right?

Comment: Your original code which uses a variadic array `_name` will cause issues with a dangling pointer (when you go out of the function, `_name` will be destroyed and your XML document will point to a region of memory that has been destroyed.

Comment: So i must declare `_name` as a pointer? Is there another way to save the xml to doc type :-?

Comment: I'd suggest using the `allocate_string` as provided by the library.

Answer (score 1):

What dirkgently said - _name is on the stack, and will be destroyed when you get out of the scope of the function. You can use allocate_string, or write your own garbage collection.

Comment: The easiest garbage collection will be just adding vector<string> member to your XmlWrapper, and push_back the string in add_node()